# LaserProjector's results differ from rviz

Tags: laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS geeks, I face a difficulty in projecting a LaserScan.

We have a rotating SICK LMS scanner which publishes laser scans relative to tf frame /laser.

Then I use LaserProjector::transformLaserScanToPointCloud to project the scan into a point cloud relative again to the /laser frame.

But when I display both the scan and the pointcloud in rviz, they differ slightly. That seem pretty odd to me, because I've seen LaserProjector being used also in rviz' laser_scan_display plugin in a very similar way (the only difference is rviz computes the pointcloud relative to the fixed frame, which is in my case /odom).

Do you have some ideas why do the two displayed things differ? Or do you have an idea on how to debug this?

Thanks for any ideas.

[image: rviz display]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205698/laserprojector%27s-results-differ-from-rviz/) by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1366 on 2015-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved.

I misused the transformLaserScanToPointCloud function to return a pointcloud in the /laser frame, which is in no means a fixed frame. However, the description of the function says it can only return pointclouds in a fixed frame for the result to make sense.

So I just use the /base_link frame as target for the conversion and now it all works :)

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2015-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0